# How Can I Improve My AI To Not Bounce Back And Forth

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

So I'm using unity3d and I have an AI. It has an invisible rectangle always facing towards a character, if the distance between the AI and the character are less than the max distance AND the invisible rectangle is not touching an obstacle then the AI will chase the character. The AI will continue patrolling if it is touching both at once (player and obstacle). But the problem is that sometimes if the player is in a certain position this happens:

The AI is not touching an obstacle and so the AI moves towards the player. Then the AI touches an obstacle behind him. So he is touching the player and a obstacle and is told to move back. As soon as he moves back a little bit he isn't touching an obstacle and is less than max distance and moves back to the player. This repeats forever giving an annoying continuous loop.

And before you answer to make the rectangle shorter, I need to tell you: I have already tried and the rectangle then doesn't detect all collisions because of the angles the rectangle turns to.

MORE INFORMATION:

- The rectangle is always facing the player exactly.

So - how can I fix this? I would really appreciate any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity has a built in navigation system for AI. That may be a better long term solution for you. You can set detection ranges etc, and it can detect obstacles pretty well automagically.

There's a great tutorial here:
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/navigation

Comment: Is there a way to make the Mac mesh agent not turn - that was the reason I stopped using him

Comment: You can make placeholder invisible object do the navigating and then tie another object to its position (but not rotation). Good to make the placeholder have a somewhat similar bounding box.

Comment: Should I use the AI that is not the nav mesh - Finite State Machine?

Comment: You can use both together. That way it can have a “patrol” state and a “chase” state etc.